# Is it possible to tell linux to look for .desktop files in a directory?

Tags: linux, .desktop, rofi

I started using `rofi` as an application launcher using its `drun` function. It works fine, `.desktop` files in `/usr/share/applications` and `$HOME/.local/share/applications` both show on it with no problems. I've been wanting to change where I keep my `.desktop` files from `$HOME/.local/share/applications` to just `$HOME/desktop`, but I can't find any way to tell linux to look for `.desktop` files in the directory I want. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want another one directory for desktop files, you need to create a directory with the name `applications` somewhere. For example:
`$HOME/desktop/applications`

Then put the path of the parent folder to the environmental variable `XDG_DATA_DIRS`.

To do this, open the file `$HOME/.profile` and add the following line to the end:

```bash
export XDG_DATA_DIRS="$HOME/desktop:$XDG_DATA_DIRS"
```

The same with the shell command:

```bash
echo 'export XDG_DATA_DIRS="$HOME/desktop:$XDG_DATA_DIRS"' >> $HOME/.profile
```

Then reboot the system (or just log out and log in again).

Answer (score 2):

Quickly looking at documentations, it appears as though it takes freedesktop.org standard directories and can't be configured to do stuff otherwise

Simple suggestion/workaround would be to make a symlink:

```
mv $HOME/.local/share/applications $HOME/desktop
ln -s $HOME/desktop $HOME/.local/share/applications
```

Comment: That works, thanks!